# network stops working for 2 mins when laptop joins network

Tags: wireless-networking

We have a working home network with 4 pcs connected to the network. 3 via ethernet and 1 via wireless. Everything is working fine. Then we have 2 more laptops which are connecting via wireless. When either of those 2 laptops joins the network, the whole network stops working for a minute or 2. After that it starts working again for everybody (including those 2 laptops). However its super annoying when it does that all the time. (The laptop goes into sleep mode, when u turn it back on again the internet(and the whole network) stops working for awhile again..).

By "the whole network stops working" I mean that I can't even ping the router when that happens. There is no response.

I have reserved the IPs (that I have assigned to the laptops) in the DHCP reservation on the router. the lease from the DHCP is set to 0 minutes (it says in the settings that 0 means 1 day). Neither laptop has a torrent or skype. I have even turned off the mcaffee antivirus but it didn't help anything.

Any ideas why it does that for those 2 laptops?
All the pcs in the network have static IPs so there is no conflict.
All the drivers are up to date.

The router is Linksys by cisco, RangePlus Wireless Router WRT110.

Let me know if you want/need any more specific data/info.
Thanks

Comment: By "the whole network" what do you mean? Does sharing stop working? Does the Internet stop working? Can you ping your router?

Comment: How long is the lease from DHCP?  How have you configured the staic IPs?  Reservation or configured manually outside DHCP scope? Are the laptops running anything like a torrent client or Skype?

Comment: No I can't even ping the router when that happens. There is no response.

Comment: I have reserved the IPs (that I have assigned to the laptops) in the DHCP reservation on the router. the lease from the DHCP is set to 0 minutes (it says in the settings that 0 means 1 day). Neither laptop has a torrent or skype. I have even turned off the mcaffee antivirus but it didn't help anything.